# ForEach method skips Console.WriteLine() on each iteration, then dumps all the logs when loop is done. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, testing, automated-tests, .net-6.0

I have this piece of code:

```cs
[Test]
public void LinqConsoleOutputTest() {
    Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList().ForEach(_ => {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Console.WriteLine($"Slept...");
    });
}
```

And to my surprise the code was executing around 5 seconds as expected, but it did not print to the console. It just dumped all 10 logs when it finished `ForEach` loop.
And I am just curious why does it work that way? Is it related to ForEach/Linq or maybe to the Console object?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/799

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine()` writes to whatever is the Standard Output which might not be a console in case of a test. Run the same code in a simple "normal" C# program and it will print as expected.

Consider this program:

```cs
namespace MyProgram;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using var fileStream = File.OpenWrite("./consoleOutput.txt");
        using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
        // redirect standard output
        Console.SetOut(streamWriter);
        Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList().ForEach(_ =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.WriteLine($"Slept... {DateTime.UtcNow}");
        });
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}
```

What this program does is, it redirects the standard output to write to a `FileStream` of a file called `consoleOutput.txt`. So when you run the program it creates the file and writes everything you would normally print to the console to the file. If you have a look at the file you can see that in fact it contains the whole output:

`consoleOutput.txt`

```
Slept... 6/3/2023 9:34:42 PM
Slept... 6/3/2023 9:34:42 PM
Slept... 6/3/2023 9:34:43 PM
Slept... 6/3/2023 9:34:43 PM
Slept... 6/3/2023 9:34:44 PM
Slept... 6/3/2023 9:34:44 PM
Slept... 6/3/2023 9:34:45 PM
Slept... 6/3/2023 9:34:45 PM
Slept... 6/3/2023 9:34:46 PM
Slept... 6/3/2023 9:34:46 PM
Done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **ITestOutputHelper in xunit** or **TestContext.WriteLine in "Nunit"** to write output that show output in "Test Details Summery"

Nunit

```
[Test]
        public void LinqConsoleOutputTest()
        {
            Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList().ForEach(_ => {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                TestContext.WriteLine($"Slept...");
              // Console.WriteLine($"Slept...");  //Console.WriteLine($"Slept...");
            });

        }
```

Xunit

```
 private readonly ITestOutputHelper _output;
        public Test(ITestOutputHelper output)
        {
            _output = output;
        }

        [Fact]
        public void LinqConsoleOutputTest()
        {
            Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList().ForEach(_ => {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                _output.WriteLine($"Slept...");
               Console.Out.WriteLine($"Slept...");  //Console.WriteLine($"Slept...");
            });
          
        }
```

[Capturing-output_Xunit](https://xunit.net/docs/capturing-output)